# What in this code is causing a Seg fault?

Tags: segmentation-fault, nasm

I am very new to Assembly programming and to learn NASM I decided to try and write a prime number testing. I wrote the code for the `is_prime` function in 32-bit elf NASM and wrote a wrapper in c++ that uses externs the NASM function. When I compiled both programs to `.o` files there were no errors, and when I linked the object files to make an executable it linked correctly. However when I try to run it I keep getting a `Segmentation Fault` error and I have no idea what this actually means or how to correct it. The code that I wrote in NASM looks like this:

```
section .bss
    n: resb 1
    i: resb 1
    m: resb 1
section .text
    global is_prime
is_prime:
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp
    mov eax,[ebp + 8]
    jmp main
main:
    mov [n],eax
    mov byte [i],2
    mov eax,[i]
    mov ebx,[n]
    cmp eax,ebx
    jge prime
    mov eax,[i]
    mov ebx,[n]
    call mod
    cmp byte [m],0
    je comp
    jmp main
mod:
    mov ecx,ebx
    xor edx,edx
    div ecx
    mov [m],edx
    ret
comp:
    mov eax,0
    jmp kill
prime:
    mov eax,1
    jmp kill
kill:
    ret
    leave
```

My main question is, am I doing something wrong in my assembly program that is causing this error and if so, how do I fix this? Or is there something wrong in the way I am linking/compiling it? I am using a 64-bit Ubuntu but I used the `-m32` and `-f elf32` options while compiling.

Comment: I think you wrote `jge prime` instead of `jge prim`.

Comment: Oh sorry that was actually a typo in the posting of the question and not in my original code. I'll fix that in the question.

Comment: `resb` reserves one _byte_ of space. The `eYx` registers are _doublewords_ (32 bits). To reserve a doubleword you should use `resd`. Also, you might want to put your `leave` instruction before the `ret`.

Comment: OK then when I write something like `cmp byte [m], 0` I shouldn't write `byte`? What should it be instead?